# Shutdown stuck on the reboot: Power down step

Tags: 16.04, laptop, shutdown

This is my shutdown screen:

[image]

I have a problem when I try to shutdown my laptop. My laptop has same issue on Ubuntu 14 as well as Ubuntu 16. I think it completely shutdown all services but stuck on the reboot: Power down.

System information:

- ThinkPad X230
- Kernel: 4.4.0-34-generic

I have tried multiple ways in Askubuntu and also tried to reinstall Ubuntu. But nothings change.

I very appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop or Server?

Comment: Did you try `shutdown -h now` in a terminal window?

Comment: @Alex: I use Ubuntu Desktop and I try to use `shutdown -h now` too but it doesn't work. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Does the `reboot` command work as expected?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, `reboot` command work well.

Comment: Try `reboot -f --poweroff`

Comment: @Alex: Your command help the laptop restart. But If It possible, I need a ways to shutdown the system.

Comment: Are you using any USB device such as modem?

Comment: Your command of choice would be 'sudo systemctl poweroff'

Answer (score 0):

If your HDD is an IDE, check if it's missing a jumper in the first two pins (master). This problem with shutdown usually is caused by this, especially with old MOBAs.