# Laptop Failed to shutdown[stuck at reboot: Power down]

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, shutdown, windows-10, reboot

I have triple boot setup with Windows 10, Kubuntu and DeepinOS.

Last night when I shut down from menu in Deepin OS it stuck at `reboot: Power down`.

However, the whole shutdown process completed, except for this last one doesn't triggered. Reboot is working fine but now I have tried to do **shutdown with Kubuntu** and it too failed at the same point.

I reinstalled Deepin OS and it again stuck at Splash

Tried Fedora, it too stuck at same point. I have to manually press power button to do shutdown .

**However, shutdown and reboot work fine with Windows 10**.

I tried `shutdown -h now`, `sudo poweroff`, BIOS reset defaults, but the problem is not solved. It always sticks at the same reboot:Power down.

Looks like i have the same issue as this: [Shutdown stuck on the reboot: Power down step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811329/shutdown-stuck-on-the-reboot-power-down-step)

[image]